# How to detect when text in QLabel is changed?

Tags: c++, qt, qlabel

In my program, I have a QLabel which can be edited by user. I have set following flags:

```
label->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextSelectableByMouse | Qt::TextEditable | Qt::TextSelectableByKeyboard);
```

I want the label to scale according to its contents. How can I detect when the text is changed, so that I could call adjustSize() on the right moment?

Comment: You mention calling adjustSize(), but adjustSize() does nothing (because sizeHint() returns an invalid size) if the QLabel is not in a layout. Howether, if the QLabel was in a proper layout, you would have no need to resize it manually. Is it, or not, in a layout ?

Comment: Thank you for answers! The label is not in a layout. What I'm trying to do, is to make the title for a uml class, and I want to resize the class if it's too small for the title. I realized that QGraphicsTextItem works better for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a layout, the label should be able to take up all the space it can. If in doubt, set the label's `QSizePolicy` to `MinimumExpanding` (width and height):

```
label->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding,
                     QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding);
```

and maybe also check adjacent widgets' size policies. If you're not using a layout, my advice: use a layout.